# Visual C++ and extremely long strings

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, boost, string-literals

I'm trying to port a third-party library to Visual C++ 2013.  The library has some extremely long strings which appear to be Base64-encoded data.  I've split them into multiple string literals, each of which is below the 2,600-odd character limit Visual C++ imposes on string literals, but even then there are some that exceed the 65,535-character limit after concatenation.

The use boils down to this:

```
boost::any value = +"abcd...";
```

Can someone suggest a way to initialize `boost::any` with over 65k of literal data?

**EDIT:** The code which does this is auto-generated from an XML file.  There are some tens of thousands of such values.  Only two are too long for the 65,535 limit.

This makes any solution that uses dynamic memory allocation (such as `std::string`) unattractive, as it will be applied by the code generation utility to all of the tens of thousands of them, when only two require it; the dynamic memory allocation will be expensive.  I'd much prefer a compile-time solution.

Comment: You could store this string data in a file and load the file's content upon initialisation.

Comment: C++ does implicit string concatenation "abc" "def". If that doesn't work, you can consider concatenation at run-time with strcpy or other.

Comment: If you do string concatenation like e.g. `std::string a = "foo"; a += "bar";` etc, then there's no problem as you no longer are having to long literals.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: for various reasons that is feasible but annoying (eg it would mean that any application that used this library would then have to carry around that file).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I did say in the question that I've split it into multiple string literals...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That would be feasible, I guess, but annoying; I'll update the question to explain why.

Comment: If you do this only once when the program is initializing, and the run-time of the program is long, will it matter that you do many reallocations at the start? Have you tried to profile it to see if it's a bottleneck? How often does this has to be done? What is the average run-time of the program? It might be "annoying", but if you only do this once does it matter?

Comment: The 2600 character limit must be a feature of the text editor, not of the compiler. You can use the array representation of the string { 'A', 'B', ... '\0' }, unfortunately not compact.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you'd be mistaken http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/64k-string-limit

Comment: @sehe: I said array of char initializer, not string literal. I just tried 200,000 characters, seamless.

Comment: @Yves it's  not a limit of the editor

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: after discussion with the developer of the original library, I've gone for the runtime concatenation option using `std::string`.

Comment: Arrays of characters may have other limits, as @YvesDaoust has mentioned:


```c++
static char const text[] = { 47, 47, 32, 74, 83, 88, 32, 45, 32, ... };
static size_t const text_length = sizeof(text);
```

V8 and Node.js projects use this way to generate such data with [js2c.py](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/tools/js2c.py) script on a build step.

I used the same approach in my project to embed JavaScript sources into program, and this initialization works fine with Visual C++ 2013, at least for a 18kiB file. While I had got the same limit error for string literals there.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the nonius revision log

```
commit ec0e32ea96e8c0b1c7068f80207c586e6c4ba7aa
Author: Martinho Fernandes <email-in-commit>
Date:   Wed Feb 19 02:44:43 2014 +0100

    Shutting up MSVC warning.
    
    Dear Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler,
    
    I hate you. After I chopped up my HTML template into tiny, tiny string pieces to appease you tiny fixed-size buffers,
    I thought we could maybe be friends after all. But no. You had to go and give me more bullshit. You had to start your
    ridiculous warning bullshit. The warning bullshit that there is no way to turn off without leaking crap to user code.
    
    You're a joke.
    
    Sincerely,
    
    rmf

commit 8f10050a3217d94af1d3fb12e1e3752ab33c8159
Author: Martinho Fernandes <email-in-commit>
Date:   Tue Feb 18 19:35:26 2014 +0100

    Now with no string pieces larger than 11k
    
    Dear Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler,
    
    It was a bit hilarious when you complained about that ~200kiB string
    literal. The standard even has only a recommendation of 64kiB. This
    16380 bytes per string piece bullshit, though? This is just ridiculous.
    
    I hope this is the last hoop I have to jump through.
    
    Sincerely,
    
    rmf

commit 6b6a098e4e43c7f8d5e5fd580f6e6be463132f81
Author: Martinho Fernandes <email-in-commit>
Date:   Tue Feb 18 19:02:05 2014 +0100

    HTML template string broken into pieces that are assembled on first use.
    
    Dear Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler,
    
    The 1990s called. They want their 64kiB fixed-size buffers back.
    I didn't pay for 32GiB of RAM so that you could whine about a string
    literal that is a few hundred kiB big.
    
    Fuck You.
    
    Sincerely,
    
    rmf
```

I can assure you that issue have been reported here

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/915771/please-hog-all-my-ram

You'll note the *customary **WONTFIX** response*. This is just formality, of course. Apparently something has changed in the newest version:

> *Is @R.MartinhoFernandes around? James told me that they've fixed the limitations on string literal lengths in VC2015 :)* — [jalf on Apr 25 10:33 PM](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=22928215#2292215)

From context, we can derive this was probably [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis).

There was an earlier conversation about the details of this limitation [on march 5th](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/64k-string-limit).

---

Comment: @JamesMcNellis are you around for comment/proper source on the linked rumour?

Comment: Yes, the James in question is McNellis. The one and only. :)

Comment: @Tom and there's good reason to expect this to be fixed in VS2015

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly is it though? Knowing that they might fix something marked as WONTFIX means that when you see WONTFIX you still have reason top hope they will fix. Instead of WONTFIX they should be clear and say "no intention to fix". Then, when you see WONTFIX you know you can just give up asking for that.

Comment: So... I have bad news.  I did say that, but it appears that I was wrong. I thought this has been improved in Visual Studio 2015, but it has not. The compiler still limits string literals to 16,380 characters. I'm sorry for having caused confusion here.