# Is there any way to get a string over the 65535 limit

Tags: c++, string, maxstringcontentlength

The max string size is 65535 bytes according to this and other SO posts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/maximum-string-length?view=msvc-160

I have been trying to google working around such as splitting strings into several and then joining them or using define.

If I download the `base64` string or read it from a file it works fine even though that still ends up being a `std::string = readfromfile` etc.

I am sure this topic has been touched on many times but I cannot find a definite answer on workarounds. I am assuming there are ones for such a popular mainstream language to not be held back by a somewhat arbitrary number.

Comment: I doubt that’s a limit of std::string

Comment: it's a limit of a single **string literal** in the source code and has nothing to do with string length

Comment: Further, that’s the maximum that Microsoft’s compiler can handle. Other compilers are probably different.

Comment: I've used `std::string` in Visual Studio to hold multiple megabytes of data. That shouldn't be your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual C++ and extremely long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341683/visual-c-and-extremely-long-strings)

Comment: The Microsoft link is not correct. Neither C nor C++ adds an extra byte to each concatinated line. Just a null byte at the end of all the concatinated lines.

Comment: [Increase string literal length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45275732/995714)

Comment: *The max string size is 65535 bytes according to this and other SO posts:* -- Well, if you had just written your program totally not knowing anything about that link you found, your program would have worked -- a mild version of [analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis).  *If* for some reason your `std::string` couldn't hold more than 65535 characters, then it would have made sense to start searching for answers.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "using define"

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code you are having a problem with